# Remove author name from facebook open graph wordpress using yoast seo

Tags: seo, wordpress, facebook-graph

I'm kinda new to wordpress and learning to use plugins instead of doing it by the code (my usual way of getting things done)

So, I have a used yoast SEO to customize my facebook cards(OG). It all works fine, expect that the card has the author name (by Rohit Nair) next to the sitename. I looked up on the source code, I can see a meta tag with author in it. But, I'm reluctant to remove it directly from the source code, since it has to be changed post by post. Can anyone suggest me better way of doing it, preferably through Yoast SEO Tool?

[image: This is how the card looks like]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question sounds like it would perhaps be a better fit on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: As noted in the comment above, this is probably best asked on our WordPress site, which has many questions about [Yoast](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=yoast+is%3Aq).